# How do I parse a Reader into a Calendar?

Tags: java, android, icalendar

I've tried to parse a reader from an `InputStreamReader` return into a Calendar with custom events but I got an URISyntaxException due to my `icalendar` file content. But I can't modify it because my purpose is to get an iCalendar data only (online file.ics) and parse them into a Calendar with iCal4j library: https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j.
So my question is how can I solve or bypass this problem?

My code :

```
public class AccesHTTP extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Controle controle;
    private String urlServ = null;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public AccesHTTP(String servaddr) {
        controle = Controle.getInstance(null);
        urlServ = servaddr;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // Create a TimeZone
        System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlServ);
            Reader r = null;
            r = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-15");
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            Calendar thisCalendar = builder.build(r);
            controle.refreshEdt(thisCalendar);
        } catch (IOException | ParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Completed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        Log.d("Return","************ " + s + " ************");
        if(s!=null){
            delegate.processFinish(s);
        };
    }
}
```

My icalendar content format:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR:CN=LASTNAME Forename :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:CN=S5A-01_ANG :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr
SUMMARY:- ang
DESCRIPTION:Professeur:LASTNAME Forename \nGroupe:S5A-01_ANG 
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20191211T080500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:20191211T093500
DTSTAMP:20200527T104154
LOCATION:B213
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:47468078
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR:CN=LASTNAME Forename :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:CN=S5A-01_ANG :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr
...
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The error code :

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 2: CN=LASTNAME Forename :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2875)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3048)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3075)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:583)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Uris.create(Uris.java:121)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Attendee.setValue(Attendee.java:109)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Attendee.<init>(Attendee.java:85)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Attendee$Factory.createProperty(Attendee.java:175)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.PropertyBuilder.build(PropertyBuilder.java:48)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.DefaultContentHandler.endProperty(DefaultContentHandler.java:123)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$PropertyParser.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:292)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$PropertyParser.access$1100(CalendarParserImpl.java:224)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$PropertyListParser.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:211)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$ComponentParser.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:427)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$ComponentParser.access$900(CalendarParserImpl.java:404)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl$PropertyListParser.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:209)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parseCalendar(CalendarParserImpl.java:115)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parseCalendarList(CalendarParserImpl.java:180)
at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:149)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your iCalendar data.

A semicolon must come after the ROLE parameter, not a colon. For example:

Incorrect: `ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR:CN=LASTNAME Forename :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr`
Correct: `ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR;CN=LASTNAME Forename :MAILTO:edt-noreply@domain.fr`

Comment: Ok thx for the note but how can I ignore a line of my icalendar file? Because I cannot modify the source of icalendar data...

Comment: @MrNem You could read the iCalendar data into a string, and then edit the string as needed before passing it into the iCalendar parser.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Michael for your help! Here it's my code which works in my situation :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // Create a TimeZone
        System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlServ);
            Reader r = null;
            r = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-15");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
            String str;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
                if(!(str.startsWith("ATTENDEE")))
                    sb.append(str + "\n");
            }
            r = new StringReader(sb.toString());
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            Calendar thisCalendar = builder.build(r);
            controle.refreshEdt(thisCalendar);
        } catch (IOException | ParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Completed";
    }
```